# Encrypting script or locking script

Tags: encryption, unix, bash

I have a bash script that I created. I would like to know is it possible to encrypt it so that no one would be able to open it and see the code? However, I would like people to run it when needed.

Operating System: Linux 3.12 (debian)

I've done some research for awhile but doesn't seem to be a straight forward answer out there. (unless I'm just wording it wrong)

The script is written in: bash

The amount of people that would use it: 5-10 people

Comment: Your question lacks detail. What methods have you tried to secure the file? What does your script do? What type of user must run the script? What OS? etc.

Comment: @schroeder that's a good idea. I will look into that . In short words that's basically what I wanted to do.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info! What does the script do? Does it need to run as each person's credentials? Shared credentials? How is it launched? Does each person manually run it? Does a system process start it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the shell script into a binary. [SHC](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/encrypt-bash-shell-script/) can do this, for instance.

If you are not married to bash, you could write it in another scripting language and compile it into a binary. Python can do this, for instance.

Please note that either way is not a secure method, but will be a barrier for the average user.

Comment: Note that this is just security by obscurity and anyone who knows what they are doing can trivially find out what this script does, merely by using a debugger or, if it is a series of system calls, just using strings on it.

Comment: @crovers agreed, as suggested in my answer

Answer (score -1):

No.  You can play silly games obfuscating, but if they are able to run it, they are able to read it, if they want to go through the effort.

In fact, that's true for every application (short of [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)) - if you can run it, you can read it.

If you absolutely need this, you'll need to read about TPM or equivalent technologies - and it'll be expensive and time consuming to do.

Answer (score -1):

This does not sound possible.  In order for the shell to run the script, it must be able to read the script.  Thus, anyone that can run the script would also be able to read the script, which defeats the purpose of encrypting it.